# Change the Brand name of Ionic cloud auth password reset email

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cloud, ionic-auth-service

im using ionic cloud for authentication in my app,

[image]

The password reset email sent has the subject Ionic App.I want to use My App Name as the subject. Not **ionic App** .

How can i achieve this .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic Auth is now Depreciated, I managed to use firebase Auth and it works like a charm